# Show copy/move Finder dialogue window

Tags: macos, finder, apple-silicon, monterey

This is something I'm very confused about (a little embarrassed too since being a mac user for a long time), but I can't find the progress window for copying or moving in Finder.

It was there and I think I accidentally `COMMAND + W` on it and it disappeared. But now I have no way of knowing how far into a copy I am without watching the pie icon in the list view.

I've tried rebooting, or relaunching Finder hoping it would fix it. I've also tried `Show all Windows` but nothing minimised. I have disconnected external displays, and made sure its not hidden behind another app.

Is this a macOS bug or am I just not reading the menu correctly?

---

#### Update:

The accepted answer helps fix the dialogue window reappearing, but after reading the command saw there is an option for it under Window - I was searching for Copy/Move but it's titled `Progress`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
defaults delete com.apple.finder CopyProgressWindowLocation && osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to quit' && open ~
```

Comment: thank you for that - helped me find there is an option for it under Window

Answer (score 0):

Normally, 'Copy' is listed as a Window in the Window menu, so you should be able to select it from there. You should also see it in 'Application Windows', which is usually <kbd>F3</kbd>. If it's not there, then something weird is definitely going on.

Also, you can't close a Finder window with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>, and even if that did do something, I wouldn't expect it to have permanent consequences.

I'd go a bit further than pion's suggestion, and remove the whole `com.apple.finder.plist` in the user's Library Preferences folder. Then restart the Finder and see if that improves things.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought! But there wasn't an option for it as a window under Window, but then I saw `Show Progress Window` and that worked. I didn't want to go down the road of deleting the entire plist but that was a last resort.. Also I retested it was CMD+W not CMD+Q